# getent hosts to take initial 3 up digit+hostname unix

Tags: python, awk, sed, cut

I need first 3 octets of IP address and the myhosts name, while I am trying to make via cut command but unable to join the host name

```
$ getent hosts myhosts
172.10.2.32    myhosts.lab.com
```

anything with awk, sed, cut, python will be okay

```
$ getent hosts myhosts | cut -d "." -f1,2,3
172.10.2
```

The output should be:

```
172.10.2  myhosts.lab.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first field, remove everything from the last dot:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",$1); print $1, $2}' <<< "172.10.2.32    myhosts.lab.com"
172.10.2 myhosts.lab.com
```

We have two fields: IP and hostname. The hostname is to be returned without any change, whereas for the IP we want to remove the last block.

To tune the first field `$1` we use [`sub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). This perform replacements using the syntax `sub(regexp, replacement [, target])`. To remove everything from the last dot, we replace it with the empty string.

And how do we match everything from the last dot? Using `/\.[^.]*$/`, which means: match a dot and then any kind of characters but a dot until the end of the field.

Comment: I edited it bit as follows which yields the same output.. 

      `{ $ getent hosts myhosts | awk '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",$1); print $0}'
      172.10.2 myhosts.lab.com }`

Comment: Please explain the regex if possible

Comment: @KarnKumar explanation added

Comment: @fedorquie .. Great Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E 's/\.[0-9]+ +/ /' <<< '172.10.2.32    myhosts.lab.com'
172.10.2 myhosts.lab.com
```

or if the white space in your command output can contain tabs or other invisible chars:

```
$ sed -E 's/\.[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+/ /' <<< '172.10.2.32    myhosts.lab.com'
172.10.2 myhosts.lab.com
```

Comment: Excellent Sed Solution, Thanks.